# Failed to load the engine in FileReaderView Flutter. Error in android platform only

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, filereader, viewer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_filereader/flutter_filereader.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class FileViewerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filePath;

  const FileViewerScreen({super.key, required this.filePath});

  @override
  State<FileViewerScreen> createState() => _FileViewerScreenState();
}

class _FileViewerScreenState extends State<FileViewerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final name = basename(widget.filePath);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(name),
        ),
        body: FileReaderView(
          filePath: widget.filePath,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using [FilReader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) Packaage. Not open/view any kind of file. Getting "引擎加载失败,请退出重试"(Failed to load the engine) error.

View files in flutter project.

Comment: if you are using flutter file reader package use this FlutterFileView.init();
 inside your iniState or something like this will be available in your package

Comment: FlutterFileView class in not present in FileReader Package. There is similar package on pub.dev site (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_view) but when i use that package than i got socketException error in project. refer this link (https://github.com/LiWenHui96/flutter_file_view/issues/17)

Comment: same problm did you find any other way to view files